# How does soda.js chaining API work for selenium testing sites using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-rc, soda

I'm attempting to create a node.js script using [soda.js](https://github.com/LearnBoost/soda/) for organizing and writing [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) scripts. The problem I am running into is that I fundamentally do not understand the [soda.js](https://github.com/LearnBoost/soda/) chaining philosophy, especially the `and()` method and the docs are very weak in explaining how it works.

Imagine the following test case:

```
var soda = require('soda');
var assert = require('assert');

var browser = soda.createClient({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 4444,
    url: 'http://www.google.com',
    browser: 'firefox'
});

browser
    .chain
    .session()
    .open("http://www.google.com", function() {
        console.log("open complete");
    })
    .and(function() {
        console.log("and");
    })
    .and(function() {
        return function(browser) {
            console.log("and2");
        }
    }())
    .end(function() {
        console.log("end");
    })
```

My understanding of the chaining API was that it was to prevent callback hell. So if I call browser.method1().method2().method3(). Then method2 would wait for method one. method3 would wait for method2() etc. Giving you the ease of synchronous, but the functionality of evented.

I expect

```
open complete
and
and2
end
```

I get

```
and
and2
open complete
end
```

What? It clearly has something to do with the `and` method, which I thought was declaring your own arbitrary functions, but it doesn't seem to be following the queue order. As you can see in the test case I've tried two methods of declaring the and function, one using a self-executing function closure, and the other with a standard anonymous function. Same result in both cases. How do I get the `and()` to follow the queue order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much banging my head I was finally able to figure out the way this works only by pouring over the source code for soda on github. Basically the `.and()` method fires immediately. Each  chained request just adds to a queue and it does not begin processing the queue until it hits an `.end()` call.

In this way, code inside an `and()` will always process before the callback from any other call. In this way `and()` is primarily used for queuing up dynamically defined actions, and it is not useful for responding to previously fired actions, those should be done in callbacks instead.

Comment: please help me on some example for callback means where to do. I have issue posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261010/nodejs-retrieving-value-from-array-show-as-un